# Would upgrading to Debian 9 allow me to use HTTP/2 with Apache?

Tags: apache-httpd

I would like to install `mod_http2`. I currently have Debian 8 with Apache 2.4.10.

I understand that it's probably not a good idea to try to manually install a later version of Apache. So, for this reason, I am considering upgrading to Debian 9. Will this allow me to use HTTP/2?

I've also read that full support for Debian 8 ends in May so I would like to upgrade for that reason also. Are there any downsides to upgrading?

Comment: Be aware PHP7 and MySQL 5.7 are significantly different from the previous versions. I would not advise migrating to Debian 9 without doing tests to your applications and define a migration plan.

Comment: And you can't run mod_php (in particular, mod_prefork) with HTTP/2, so you'll have to use php-fpm. At that point you may as well just switch to nginx.

Comment: I've never used Nginx. Would the version of Nginx available on Debian 8 be able to use HTTP/2? (In this case, I'm just going to upgrade Debian but I'm interested to know.)

Comment: To answer my own question, yes it does but I believe it has to be installed via Jessie Backports.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Will this allow me to use HTTP/2?

Yes, it will allow you to use it.

> Are there any downsides to upgrading?

Not really, no.

---

First, you will need to enable the module:

```
sudo a2enmod http2
```

You can then simply add a line to this file:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

The line should look like:

```
# Enabling HTTP/2 (NPN)
Protocols h2 http/1.1
```

Finally, please restart your Apache.

Comment: cool idea. +1 for both the answer and question.

Comment: Thanks guys. Having just set up HTTP/2 for Ubuntu 16.04 I'll just say that anyone reading this and wondering why HTTP/2 doesn't work will probably need to `a2dismod mpm_prefork` then run PHP with FastCGI instead. Not all the guides tell you this, so I thought it might be useful to someone.

Comment: Thank you sdexp for the tip! I found this article which @Vlastimil posted his exact steps [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/456941/313532) that worked for me.