# How to enable Apache2 HTTP/2 on version 2.4.33 in Debian Stretch?

Tags: debian, apache-httpd

Today, I ran an upgrade as every week of my Debian web server.

I was greeted with message:

> ```
> apache2 (2.4.25-3+deb9u5) stretch; urgency=medium
>  * This package upgrades mod_http2 to the version from apache2 2.4.33. This
>    fixes a lot of bugs and some security issues, but it also removes the
>    support for using HTTP/2 when running with mpm_prefork. HTTP/2 support
>    is only provided when running with mpm_event or mpm_worker.
> -- Stefan Fritsch <sf@debian.org>  Sat, 02 Jun 2018 09:51:46 +0200
> ```

Which surprised me, because I use HTTP/2 on my server. I tested my server on [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/), and really the HTTP/2 is gone.

How do I remedy it supposing I use the official Apache and PHP 7.0 packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case I applied the following as `root` to get it running again:

```sh
# enable these mods
a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif

# disable standard PHP module
a2dismod php7.3

# if you don't have FPM already installed
apt-get install php7.3-fpm

# query the MPM
a2query -M
```

If you see `prefork` or `worker`, you need to continue with the following steps. If you see `event`, you can skip the next 2 steps.

```sh
# disable the prefork / worker MPM (only one MPM can run at a time)
a2dismod mpm_prefork mpm_worker

# enable event MPM
a2enmod mpm_event

# start and enable the FastCGI Process Manager
systemctl start php7.3-fpm && systemctl enable php7.3-fpm

# enable the FastCGI Process Manager configuration
a2enconf php7.3-fpm

# start Apache2 web server
systemctl restart apache2
```

Tested to be working on GNU/Linux Debian 10 Buster on **2019-Apr-11**.

---

Now, you can finally enable the HTTP/2 through ALPN.

You can do this globally for all of your sites in this file:

```sh
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

With the following directive:

```sh
Protocols h2 http/1.1
```